On estimation of multivariate density function
Let $(X,Y)$ be non-negative absolutely continuous random vector with probability density function $f(x,y)$. Also random samples $\{X_{1i},X_{2i}\}$ are i.i.d.  Then kernel density estimator of $f$ is given by
$$\widehat{f}(x,y)=\frac{1}{nh_xh_y}\sum_{i=1}^n k\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h_x},\frac{y-y_i}{h_y}\right)=\frac{1}{nh_xh_y}\sum_{i=1}^n k\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h_x}\right)k\left(\frac{y-y_i}{h_y}\right),$$
where $h_x$ and $h_y$ represent bandwidth parameter and $K$ is kernel.
Using some data I estimated the kernel density estimation:
library(ks)

# Your scaled data for X and Y
X <- c(0.95230999, 0.00596125, 0.00298063, 0.89716841, 0.16244411, 0.01490313, 
       0.1609538, 0.16244411, 0.29508197, 0.05812221, 0.5633383, 0.60804769, 
       0.05365127, 0.30849478, 1, 0.04023845, 0.12965723, 0.37853949, 0, 0.57824143)

Y <- c(0.01195652, 0.27318841, 0.21557971, 0.12318841, 0.21630435, 0.22572464, 
       0.03550725, 0.32971014, 0.13007246, 0.22644928, 0.22427536, 0, 
       1, 0.54311594, 0.36775362, 0.18152174, 0.0884058, 0.19565217, 
       0.08514493, 0.0807971)

# Combine X and Y into a matrix
data_matrix <- cbind(X, Y)

# Bandwidth selection using plug-in method (Hpi)
H <- Hpi(x = data_matrix)  # Plug-in bandwidth selection method
print(H)
kde_result <- kde(x = data_matrix, H = H)
plot(kde_result, cont = c(50, 75, 95))  # Contours for 50%, 75%, and 95% levels

My question is 'How do we estimate $$G(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,t),$$ where $F$ is the joint distribution function and $t$ is some positive real number.
Kernel estimation of $G(x,t)$ is given as
$$\widehat{G}(x,t)=\frac{1}{nh_xh_y}\sum_{i=1}^n k\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h_x}\right)K\left(\frac{y-y_i}{h_y}\right),$$
where $$K(z)=\int_0^z k(x)dx.$$ For further details see here.
Question: My question is how to choose bandwidth for this estimation? Like I did for (,) in R code, in the similar way I want to estimate (,) using R.

Can you give us a link where that $F$ is used please?

Please see my edits, I have also forgot to mention some important details. Please go through the problem again. Thank you so much!

Thank you for the changes; please notice that your $k$ and $K$ are a bit mixed and that $\hat{G}$ doesn't seem to use $t$.

Anyway, is there a reason as not why we don't want to use numerical derivatives directly? It's not like that $G$ has some pristine analytical form.

That $t$ can take any value. Actually I am doing non-parametric estimation.

What are you trying to ask, given that the last several lines of your post provide the answer?

My question is how to choose bandwidth for this estimation? Like I did for $f(x,y)$ in R code, in the similar way I want to estimate $G(x,t)$ using R.
